# App crashes when moving from splash screen to playlist

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to build a videoplayer, i managed to get the logo screen but when my app move from logo to playlist...it crashes

```
package com.example.droid;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.widget.ListView;``
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;


class VidFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name){
        return (name.endsWith(".3gp"));
    }   
}

      public class playlist extends ListActivity {
          private long id;
          private String title;  
          private ArrayList<playlist> videoList;
          private ListView videoView;


          @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.videoplaylist);
             videoView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myList);
             videoList = new ArrayList<playlist>();
             getvideoList();

             VideoAdapter VAdap = new VideoAdapter(this, videoList);
             videoView.setAdapter(VAdap);


             Collections.sort(videoList, new Comparator<playlist>(){
                 public int compare(playlist a, playlist b){
                     return a.getTTL().compareTo(b.getTTL());

          }
          });

          }

          public void getvideoList(){
              //retrieve video info
              ContentResolver videoResolver = getContentResolver();
              Uri videoUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
              Cursor videoCursor = videoResolver.query(videoUri, null, null, null, null);

              if (videoCursor!=null && videoCursor.moveToFirst()){

                  int titleColumn = videoCursor.getColumnIndex
                          (android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE);

                  int idColumn = videoCursor.getColumnIndex
                          (android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);
                  //add video to list
                  do {
                      long thisId = videoCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                      String thisTitle = videoCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                      videoList.add(new playlist(thisId, thisTitle));
                  }
                  while (videoCursor.moveToNext());

              }

          }

      public playlist(long videoID, String videoTitle) {
        id= videoID;  
        title=videoTitle;}

        public long getID(){return id;}
        public String getTTL(){return title;}

        public static playlist get(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

      }
```

11-27 17:42:58.409: I/Process(19075): Sending signal. PID: 19075 SIG: 9
11-27 17:43:04.429: E/MoreInfoHPW_View(19485): Parent view is not a TextView
11-27 17:43:04.519: D/dalvikvm(19485): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 211K, 12% free 16218K/18404K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
11-27 17:43:04.519: D/Activity(19485): #3 setTransGradationModeColor to false
11-27 17:43:04.579: I/Adreno-EGL(19485): : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
11-27 17:43:04.579: I/Adreno-EGL(19485): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.02.11
11-27 17:43:04.579: I/Adreno-EGL(19485): Build Date: 09/04/14 Thu
11-27 17:43:04.579: I/Adreno-EGL(19485): Local Branch: LA.3.6.1_20140904_070_patches
11-27 17:43:04.579: I/Adreno-EGL(19485): Remote Branch: 
11-27 17:43:04.579: I/Adreno-EGL(19485): Local Patches: 
11-27 17:43:04.579: I/Adreno-EGL(19485): Reconstruct Branch: 
11-27 17:43:04.599: I/HWUI(19485): EGLImpl-HWUI Protected EGL context created
11-27 17:43:04.599: I/qdutils(19485): PartialUpdate status: Enabled
11-27 17:43:04.599: I/qdutils(19485): Left Align: 8
11-27 17:43:04.599: I/qdutils(19485): Width Align: 8
11-27 17:43:04.599: I/qdutils(19485): Top Align: 1
11-27 17:43:04.599: I/qdutils(19485): Height Align: 1
11-27 17:43:04.599: I/qdutils(19485): Min ROI Width: 1
11-27 17:43:04.599: I/qdutils(19485): Min ROI Height: 2
11-27 17:43:04.599: I/qdutils(19485): Needs ROI Merge: 1
11-27 17:43:04.599: I/qdutils(19485): Left Split=720
11-27 17:43:04.599: I/qdutils(19485): Right Split=720
11-27 17:43:04.609: D/OpenGLRenderer(19485): Enabling debug mode 0
11-27 17:43:09.579: D/dalvikvm(19485): newInstance failed: no ()
11-27 17:43:09.579: D/AndroidRuntime(19485): Shutting down VM
11-27 17:43:09.579: W/dalvikvm(19485): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418efda0)

**11-27 17:43:09.579: E/AndroidRuntime(19485): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 17:43:09.579: E/AndroidRuntime(19485): Process: com.example.droid, PID: 19485
11-27 17:43:09.579: E/AndroidRuntime(19485): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.droid/com.example.droid.playlist}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.droid.playlist; no empty constructor
11-27 17:43:09.579: E/AndroidRuntime(19485):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
11-27 17:43:09.579: E/AndroidRuntime(19485):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
11-27 17:43:09.579: E/AndroidRuntime(19485):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
11-27 17:43:09.579: E/AndroidRuntime(19485):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
11-27 17:43:09.579: E/AndroidRuntime(19485):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-27 17:43:09.579: E/AndroidRuntime(19485):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
11-27 17:43:09.579: E/AndroidRuntime(19485):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5748)
11-27 17:43:09.579: E/AndroidRuntime(19485):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 17:43:09.579: E/AndroidRuntime(19485):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-27 17:43:09.579: E/AndroidRuntime(19485):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
11-27 17:43:09.579: E/AndroidRuntime(19485):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
11-27 17:43:09.579: E/AndroidRuntime(19485):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-27 17:43:09.579: E/AndroidRuntime(19485): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.droid.playlist; no empty constructor
11-27 17:43:09.579: E/AndroidRuntime(19485):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
11-27 17:43:09.579: E/AndroidRuntime(19485):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
11-27 17:43:09.579: E/AndroidRuntime(19485):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
11-27 17:43:09.579: E/AndroidRuntime(19485):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2399)
11-27 17:43:09.579: E/AndroidRuntime(19485):    ... 11 more
11-27 17:43:12.009: I/Process(19485): Sending signal. PID: 19485 SIG: 9**

Comment: No empty constructor. This is needed to fullfill bean property

Comment: Are you trying to instantiate a playlist when it is an activity? What the heck is going on in that code? Please go learn Android basics

Answer (score 0):

the logcat output says there is no empty constructor in your `playlist` class and you have to define it.